# Is there a way to configure/control which fields appear in batch edit mode for a collection in Directus?

Tags: directus

Is there configuration option to control which fields appear in batch edit mode in directus [image: directus batch edit mode]

Answer (score 0):

Not as of now, there is no permission/setting for changing visibility based on batch edit. That would be a good feature request though!

https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md